# Creating a CSV File with PHP

Tags: php

PHP - I have read and used many of the answers, but I keep getting the HTML
of the page as well, how do I stop this!!, or am I just stupid, no don't
answer that. (the new formatted version, sorry guys!!!)

Here is the code:

```
function WriteCSVFile( $csvArr, $nLine )  
{  
    header( "Content-type: text/csv" );  
    header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv" );  
    header( "Pragma: no-cache" );  
    header( "Expires: 0" );  
    header( "Cache-control: private" );  
    header( "Cache-control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );  

    for( $nLoop = 0; $nLoop <= $nLine; $nLoop++ )  
        echo $csvArr[$nLoop];  
}
```

Comment: Use the MIME type `text/csv` for CSV files. That should make your browser treat it like a CSV.

Comment: Also, please indent any code by 4 spaces. This is unreadable.

Comment: Thanks Amadan, I thought I did, will try hardeer next time.

Comment: Do you have any output before calling 'WriteCSVFile' function?

Answer (score 1):

You are looping the following before you ouput any headers:

```
for( $nLoop = 0; $nLoop <= $nLine; $nLoop++ )
    echo $csvArr[$nLoop] . "<br />";
```

Stick that after your `header()`

**EDIT**

As I did this 'before' you changed it, I will still leave the `for` loop still.  One thing I will point out is that you are calling a `function WriteCSVFile( $csvArr, $nLine )`

But you never tell us how this `fn()` is being called, it could be that something BEFORE this function is outputting and therefore you have html, your headers won't matter if you already have something outputting to the user.

Check what is being output (what HTML??) then search for that exact html in your php code.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that, but if you notice I did that, the first loop is a dummy debug for me, to make sure i have the correct info, just to make sure it wasn't affeting it I commented it out as follows:

Comment: Note first loop is removed, but still outputting HTML

Comment: @Hans Engel - Thanks Hans, changed as above, but again still getting HTML, I've double checked code to make sure array is clean.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right, the page is a potpourri of html, js, css & php which reads data from a MySQL db and displays to end user, however the end user also needs to dowload result to an excel file. So I am stuck. I think I might create a table on the fly and try exporting that to CSV. What do you think??

Answer (score 0):

```
for( $nLoop = 0; $nLoop <= $nLine; $nLoop++ )
    echo $csvArr[$nLoop] . "\n";
```

If the items of `$csvArr` are arrays itself, you probably want to `implode()` the values to a single line

```
for( $nLoop = 0; $nLoop <= $nLine; $nLoop++ )
    echo implode(',', $csvArr[$nLoop]) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
```

Or check whether you have any output before calling the `WriteCSVFile` function. If so it will return erros saying can't modify header information.